# Custom datetime format in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to output a string that represents the current date/time in a format like this "yyyyMMddHHmm". For example, "201310310759" for "7:59am on 10/31/2013".

This is what I have so far:

```
Date.today.to_formatted_s(:db).gsub("-","")
```

Comment: Be careful using `"yyyyMMddHHmm"` as an example because it can confuse those answering. `M` means minute, not month which is `m`. What you're really meant was `yyyymmddHHMM`, and translates to `'%Y%m%d%H%M'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

You can check other options [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)